# JSONDecoder does not work for Swift code (SWIFT UI)

Tags: swift, jsondecoder

I'm trying to decode data from JSONDecoder and API for my app.

fetchDate() in ContentVeiw.swift works, but decodedResponse is nil which means JSONDecoder needs to be fixed.

How do I fix this?

Here's my code.

ContentView.Swift

```
 func fetchData() async {
        let urlString = "http://carbonateapiprod.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/mealprovidingunits/\(restaurant.mealProvidingUnitID)/dishoccurrences?startDate=2022-04-04&endDate=2022-04-08"
        print(urlString)
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            print("Bad URL: \(urlString)")
            return
        }
        
        do {
            
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Restaurants.self, from: data) {
                restaurants = decodedResponse.restaurants
                print("here") // doesn't work! 
            }
            
            loadingState = .loaded
            print("here!")

        } catch {
            loadingState = .failed
            print("here?")
        }
    }
```

Restaurants.swift

```
import Foundation

struct Restaurants: Codable {
var restaurants: [Restaurant]
}
```

Restaurant.swift

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Restaurant
struct Restaurant: Codable, Identifiable {
let id, startDate, endDate, dishID: String
let mealProvidingUnitID: String
let mealProvidingUnit: MealProvidingUnit
let displayNames: [DisplayName]
let dishTypeID: String
let dishType: DishType
let dish: Dish
let availableDishTypes: [DishType]
let editableByDefault: Bool ....
```

JSON data looks like this

```
[
 {
 "id": "1a3f866d-0670-4d06-9118-08da019145a7",
 "startDate": "4/6/2022 12:00:00 AM",
 "endDate": "4/6/2022 12:00:00 AM",
 "dishID": "9cfcb36c-0ff9-4bf5-b4e5-db0b2a4f0894",
 "mealProvidingUnitID": "21f31565-5c2b-4b47-d2a1-08d558129279",
 "mealProvidingUnit": {
   "id": "21f31565-5c2b-4b47-d2a1-08d558129279",
   "mealProvidingUnitName": "Kårrestaurangen",
   "organizationID": "11fbbb8c-14f0-44f4-7457-08d556947c13",
   "showFoods": true,
   "showArticles": true,
   "longitude": 0.0,
   "latitude": 0.0,
   "sevenDayWeek": false,
   "displayNameCategories": null,
   "dishTypes": [
     {
      "id": "16ea0d5a-8082-4b8a-9003-08d621fbccd9",
      "dishTypeName": "Classic Vegan",
      "dishTypeNameEnglish": "Classic Vegan",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "price": 0.0,
      "hasPrice": false
    } ...
```

Comment: Instead of `try? JSONDecoder().decode(` use `try!` so your application crashes. Then include the error message in your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your 'Restaurant' struct is wrong. Run a sample of your `JSON` through [JSON Formatter](jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) and once you know it is valid, run it through [quicktype](app.quicktype.io) to get the proper decoding classes. Once that is done, fix your decoding classes and put your try statements in a proper `do catch` and print any errors in the `catch` block.

Comment: Your decoded `Restaurants` response is nil, most likely because you are using `http` instead of the required `https`.
So, unless you have setup your `NSAppTransportSecurity` accordingly, you are getting an error message, not the `Restaurants`. In any case, add `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))`  just after `let (data, _) = try await ...` 
and show us what it prints.

Answer (score 1):

use this example code (works for me). Your `Restaurants` struct does not match the json data, there is no
`restaurants` field in the json data. However, `[Restaurant]` does fit the json data. See also my comment regarding `https`.

```
   let urlString = "https://carbonateapiprod.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/mealprovidingunits/\(restaurant.mealProvidingUnitID)/dishoccurrences?startDate=2022-04-04&endDate=2022-04-08"
```

and

```
   if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Restaurant].self, from: data) {
       restaurants = decodedResponse
       print("\n \(restaurants) \n")
   }
```